# PhpStorm Search Everywhere is not working, do you know the solution?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I don't know this is off topic or not, I'm using general channels. Is there a solution for Search Anywhere in PhpStorm. I work with Laravel but when I use the feature I can't find the file even though it exists.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your screenshot: it looks to me like ALL of your files are considered excluded / outside of the project for some reason (based on the fact that ALL files in the project tree have that background color). Try: 1) close project, 2) delete your `.idea` subfolder and then 3) create a new project in PhpStorm from scratch (just point to the folder)

Comment: Wow, this is working thank you very much for the solution and contribution, have a nice day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot: based on the fact that ALL files in the project tree have that sort of "dirty yellow" background color... it looks like ALL of your files are considered excluded / outside of the project for some reason.

Most likely a user error of some kind. E.g. you may have opened it from a different path (i.e. when symlink is involved), may have c=misconfigured it later somehow (marked folder as Excluded by mistake or whatnot) or maybe even some sort of config file corruption (pretty unlikely).

Anyway, please do this:

1. Close your project
2. Go to the project root folder and delete your `.idea` subfolder (that's where your project settings are stored).
3. If you have that project still visible in the IDE (Recent Projects on the Welcome screen) -- you may remove it there as well (to avoid any possible confusion).
4. Now create a new project in PhpStorm from scratch using existing files: just use "Open" and point to the folder with your project.

Answer (score -1):

Please check `filter` option. If you are doing file search then click on `Files` tab.